# Host web browser can't access docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome

I executed a service in a docker container and I exposed container port `8080` to host port `6000`.
Command:

```
docker run \
    -d \
    --rm \
    --name keycloak \
    -p 6000:8080 \
    -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
    -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak \
    -b 0.0.0.0 \
    -Djboss.http.port=8080
```

Result of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
71c6a8ea6529        quay.io/keycloak/keycloak   "/opt/jboss/tools/do…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6000->8080/tcp   keycloak
```

Result of `docker inspect keycloak`

```
"Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "6000"
                    }
                ],
                "8443/tcp": null
            },
```

Result of `ps aux | grep docker`

```
root        1481  0.0  0.5 1600328 83560 ?       Ssl  18:17   0:02 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root        2995  0.0  0.0 549300  4448 ?        Sl   18:18   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 6000 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
root        3009  0.0  0.0 109104  5140 ?        Sl   18:18   0:00 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/71c6a8ea6529bdcb1a04d5fa73b5ca0053a4d012905d592b6b342f1b0e8c9047 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
```

When I use `curl` then it can reach service inside container. `curl -v http://localhost:6000/auth`

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:6000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6000 (#0)
> GET /auth/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, no-store
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
< Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2020 17:44:03 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Robots-Tag: none
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 4070
```

When I try to the same in the google-chrome web browser then I got an error:

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost:6000/auth/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

Why can't the Google Chrome browser access the docker service using `localhost` and the exposed port?

Comment: Does Incognito work?

Comment: @AssaelAzran No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port 6000 is by default used by X11 and as such considered unsafe by Chrome (see [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc) for a list of other unsafe, blocked ports and [here](https://jazzy.id.au/2012/08/23/why_does_chrome_consider_some_ports_unsafe.html) for an explanation).

You need to change it to one of the ports considered safe or start Chrome like this:

```
chrome --explicitly-allowed-ports=6000
```

Comment: I changed the port to `7000` and it is working in google-chrome. I don't understand because I tried `8080` and `8180` either, but none of them worked before.

Comment: Those aren't considered unsafe, so there must have been some other issue.

Comment: I also have experienced same problem. I found out, if you use docker-compose to build and run the container with exact same parameter (port, env, image etc) it works as it should!